# how to execute hql with jdbc in java ,when metastore is mysql

Tags: java, hadoop, jdbc, hive, hiveql

I have hadoop env ,the hive metasotre is mysql.

I can connect to mysql with configured username/passwd use jdbc in java successfully.

But I have some hive sql ,like

[CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS]

[SELECT PERCENTILE_APPROX(LOG.QUERY_LATENCY,0.9) FROM Table],this is not supported in mysql.

So ,how can I connect hive env and execute hive sql when metastore is mysql?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the HiveServer2 then try using below code snippet:

```
private static String driver = "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver";
.
.
.
    Connection connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive2://<host>:port/default","","");
    Statement state = connect.createStatement();
   // Query to show tables
    String show = "show tables";
    ResultSet res = state.executeQuery(show);
```

I am using Hive Version 0.13 with that I am using Hive Driver version 1.1.0
My POM Dependency for Hive Driver:
    
        org.apache.hive
        hive-jdbc
        1.1.0